# Area in $uv$ plane corresponding to two areas in $xy$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, change-of-variable

The inequalities $1 \leq x^2 - y^2 \leq 4$ and $3 \leq xy \leq 5$ describe the area $D$. See picture below. [image: Inequalities graphed.]

The excerice is to calculate the integral: $\iint_D 2(x^4 - y^4) \,dx\,dy$

I would do a vaiable substitution where $u = x^2 - y^2$ and $v = xy$ where $1 \leq u \leq 4, 3 \leq v \leq 5$, with the corresponding Jacobian $\frac{\partial(u, v)}{\partial(x, y)} = 2(x^2 + y^2) = 2u \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)} = \frac{1}{2(x^2 + y^2)}$.

Doing the integral, we get

$\int_{1}^{4} \int_{3}^{5} 2 (x^4 - y^4) \, |\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)}| \, du \, dv = \int_{1}^{4} \int_{3}^{5} 2 (x^2 + y^2) (x^2 - y^2) \frac{1}{2(x^2 + y^2)} \,du\,dv =  \int_{1}^{4} \int_{3}^{5} u \,du \,dv = 15$.

---

As one clearly sees, the inequalities corresponds to two areas in $xy$; one in the first quadrant and one in the third quadrant.

How do I know if which area I've integrated over when I do the variable substitution? Is it the one in the first or third quadrant or both? Or is it indifferent?

To me it looks like the $uv$ inequalities correspond to both areas in $xy$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

To integrate we need also to express the intagrand function $2(x^4 - y^4)$ in terms of $u$ and $v$

We can proceed as follow

- $x^4 - y^4=(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)=u\sqrt{u^2+4v^2}$

Comment: I know, I kinda skipped a lot of steps in my calcuations as it's not my main point.

Comment: @eirik-ff ah ok your main question is about the area we are integrating

Comment: Correct! It confuses me since to me it's ambiguous which area we're integrating over.

Comment: @eirik-ff then here you should write $$\int_{1}^{4} \int_{3}^{5} 2 (x^4 - y^4) \, |\frac{\partial(x, y)}{\partial(u, v)}| \, du \, dv = \int_{1}^{4} \int_{3}^{5} f(u,v)u \,du \,dv $$

Comment: By the change of variable, the curvilinear square bounded by the hyperbolas becomes a square in the plane $u,v$. Therefore the new integral should be doubled to take into account that the original integral refers to the a double area in the first and third quadrant.

Comment: I just noticed I had a typo in my original post. I've edited now for clarity. The Jacobian is $\frac{1}{2 (x^2 + y^2)}$ which cancels the integrad nicely, leaving us with $\int_{1}^{4} \int_{3}^{5} u \,du\,dv$.

Comment: Regarding your other statement, should I always double the integral whenever there's two areas represented by the same inequalities? If there's four areas, should I then multiply with 4?

Comment: @eirik-ff ah ok, sorry but I didn't check all the derivation.